# Show that if $|f(z)| \leq M |z|^n$ then $f$ is a polynomial max degree n

Tags: complex-analysis

I can't prove this statement, can anybody show me how to prove it?

$$f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C} \in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}), \exists n\in \mathbb{N}, R >0 , M>0 : |f(z)| \le M|z|^{n} \ \ \forall |z|>R \Rightarrow \deg(f)\le n $$

To show is that if there exists such an $M$, that then $f$ is a polynomial of max degree $n$. I started like this:

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n$$ So if I put this into the inequality: $$|f(z)| = \left| \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n \right| \le M |z|^n .$$

Comment: Remark: there is a list of similar questions [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34548/80734)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We have for $k\geq 1$, $z_0\in\mathbb C$ fixed and $r$ such that $\{z,|z-z_0|=r\}\subset\{z\in\mathbb C,|z|\geq R\}$, we have thanks to the Cauchy integral formula
$$f^{(n+k)}(z_0) =\frac{(n+k+1)!}{2i\pi}\int_{C(z_0,r)}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+k+1}}dz,$$
hence 
$$|f^{(n+k)}(z_0)|\leq \frac{(n+k+1)!}{2\pi}\int_{C(z_0,r)}M\frac{|z|^n}{r^{n+k+1}}\leq \frac{(n+k+1)!}{r^{n+k+1}}M(r+|z_0|)^n.$$
Since it's true for $r$ large enough, we get that $f^{(n+k)}(z_0)=0$ for each $z_0$ and $k\geq 1$, which show that $f$ is a polynomial of max degree $n$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I got a bit confused, why exactly do we deduce that n is the maximum degree?

Comment: The degree cannot be larger than $n$ because $|f(z)|\leqslant |z|^n$ (consider this inequality for $z$ with large modulus).

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Hi, I faced the same problem but I am restricted to use the coefficients of the Taylor series for $f$ to prove it. So any hint or guidlines? Thanks

Comment: @DavideGiraudo can we solve it using rouché's theorem?

Comment: Sir, can you explain the last step? I mean how you get $M(r+|z_0|)^n$?

Comment: @GeneralMathematics By the triangle inequality, $|z|\leq |z-z_0|+|z_0|=r+|z_0|$.

Comment: Thanks sir, for replying to such an old post.