# How do I find the polynomial degree of f?

Tags: functions

Suppose $f$ is an entire function such that $$\dfrac{| f(z) |}{|z|^4} \leq  100|z|^{11}$$ for $z > 120$. Is $f$ a polynomial of degree $\leq15$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143468/entire-function-bounded-by-a-polynomial-is-a-polynomial