# Essential singularity in sine function

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Let  $$f(z)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{z^2+1}\right)$$

How can I show that $z=i$ is an essential singularity?

I have tried many things like expanding, or derivate. But I can't get something. Some ideas or hint will be useful.

Comment: Going from the wikipedia article, you can show that the limit as z approaches i of $f(z)$ and $\frac 1 {f(z)}$ both do not exist.

Comment: but non-existence is not enougth to say that is an essential singularity.

Comment: Have you tried expanding the function into a Laurent series about $z=i$?

Comment: I have but it's to hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $i$ is **not** an essential singularity, then there is an integer $k$ such that 
$$\lim_{z\to i}(z-i)^k f(z) = 0\tag1$$
hence
$$\lim_{z\to i}(z^2+1)^k f(z) = 0\tag2$$

After the change of variable $\zeta=\pi/(z^2+1)$ equation (2) yields
$$\lim_{\zeta\to \infty} \zeta^{-k} \sin \zeta=0 \tag{3}$$
But [Entire function bounded by a polynomial is a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/143468/).