# Prove an entire function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $f(0)=1, f'(0)=0$, and
$$
0<|f(z)|\leq e^{|z|}
$$
for every $z\in \mathbb{C}$. Prove $f$ is constant $1$ on $\mathbb{C}$.

I am going to use Cauchy estimate similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143881) . but I found it does not work, can you give me some hint?

Comment: Do you know Liouville's theorem? Try to show that $f(z)e^{-z}$ is constant.

Comment: @Crostul I know it, but I cannot show$|f(z)e^{-z}|\leq |f(z)|e^{-|z|}$, so I cannot prove it is bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition $0<|f(z)|$ is very important. From this we see that $f(z)= e^{g(z)}$ for some entire function $g(z)$.
Then the condition  $$
|f(z)|=e^{\operatorname{Re}g(z)}\le e^{|z|}
$$
implies $$
\operatorname{Re}g(z)\le |z|.
$$
If you can conclude from this that $g(z)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $1$, that is, $g(z)=az+b$, then the condition $f(0)=1,f^\prime(0)=0$ yields that $f$ is constant $1$.

Comment: what theorem guarantee there is an entire function $g$ such that $f(z)= e^{g(z)}$

Comment: See, for example, Conway's book, p.94, **6.17 Corollary** which states:
Let $G$ be simply connected and let $f:G\to \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function such that $f(z)\ne 0$ for any $z$ in $G$. Then there is an analytic function $g:G\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=\exp g(z)$.
Outline of the proof:
Consider a primitive $g$ of $f^\prime/f$ and $h=\exp g$. Then $f/h$ should be a constant.

Comment: Can you give further hint to conclude that $g(z)$ is polynomial of degree at most 1? I know that  $\text{Re } g(z)\leq |z|$ but we don't have $|g(z)|\leq |z|$ so we can't use Cauchy's Estimate to prove that.

Comment: @Alan Wang  Let $f$ be an entire function, and $f=u+iv=\sum a_n z_n$ is its Taylor series. 
If $A(r)=\max_{|z|=r}u$, then
$$
|a_n|r^n \leq \max\{4A(r),0\}-2u(0).
$$
For the proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2596979/estimate-for-the-coefficients-in-taylor-series-of-a-analytic-function/2597941#2597941).  The proof is valid for entire functions.

Now if $g(z)=\sum a_n z_n$ satisfies 
$$
\operatorname{Re}g(z)\le |z|,
$$
then for $n\ge 2$
$$
|a_n|\leq 4r^{1-n}-2u(0)r^{-n}\to 0\,(n\to \infty).
$$
Therefore $g(z)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $1$.