# Entire Function, Boundary Values $\limsup$, $\liminf$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $f$ be a non-constant entire function with infinitely many $z_n$ such that $f(z_n)=0$.

Define $M(r):= \max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$.

Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

1. $\limsup \frac{M(r)}{r^n} = \infty$.
2. $\liminf \frac{M(r)}{r^n} = 0$. (**EDIT:** found by the answerer Yiorgos to be **incorrect**)

Can someone give a hint? The only idea I have is that $f$ is not a polynomial and therefore has no limit at $\infty$. So it has an essential singularity at $\infty$, and for every possible complex value, there exists a subsequence with the limit being that value. This way, the $\limsup$ is $0$ and the $\liminf $ is $\infty$.

Comment: do you know about cauchy inequalities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first, since $f$ is non-constant, the roots tend to infinity, and it is not a polynomial. Thus
$$
\limsup_{r\to\infty}\frac{M(r)}{r^n}=\infty,
$$
for otherwise the above limit would be finite, for $n$ equal to the degree of the polynomial.

The second is NOT true. For example
$$
f(z)=e^z-1,
$$
then
$$
M(r)\ge e^r-1,
$$
and hence
$$
\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{M(r)}{r^n}=\infty=\liminf_{r\to\infty}\frac{M(r)}{r^n}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Also I think this question is worth mentioning here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143468/entire-function-bounded-by-a-polynomial-is-a-polynomial

Comment: Why does $\limsup_{r\to\infty}\frac{M(r)}{r^n}$ not being $\infty$ implies $f$ must be a polynomial? I guess one would have to prove that this implies $|f(z)|< k|z|^n$ for large $|z|^n$ as it was suggested in the above comment, but I don't see clearly how would the proof go. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've thought of using Maximum Modulus Principle, but I'm not sure how a proof would go since $M(r)\to \infty$ but $\frac{1}{r^n} \to 0$ as $r\to \infty$.