# A complex polynomial $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ is surjective.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Consider a non-constant polynomial in $\mathbb C$ and consider the map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ that it encodes. Is it possible to show it is a surjective function? We know it is one because of the fundamental theorem of algebra. But would we be able to prove it without knowing it is a polynomial?

As a particular example we can consider the polynomial $x^3-2x^2-4$ and see it encodes the map $f(x,y) = (x^3 + 2 x^2 - 3 x y^2 - 2 (y^2 + 2), y (3 x^2 + 4 x - y^2))$

Is there some sort of theory that encompasses this phenomenon and can be used to say functions of this kind are surjective (without knowing a-priori the expression is of this kind)? Like maybe some sort of invariant that can be calculated for the expression or something.

Comment: Do you mean maps induced by complex holomorphic functions? They are identified by satisfying the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations). And if they are entire (holomorphic on all of $\mathbb R^2$) then their range misses at most one point by the [Little Picard Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem). The only non-surjective ones are of the form $e^{h(z)}+c$, with $h$ entire and $c$ a constant, see [Surjective entire functions on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/270804/51484).

Comment: Yeah that works well, I guess it is easy to check our functions are not of that form? (polynomials in x and y)

Comment: Just take partial derivatives and see if they satisfy CRE.

Comment: I mean that they are not one of the non-surjective ones

Comment: Not necessarily, there are some sufficient conditions on MO, but there is no constructive criterion.

Comment: but the MO question seems to assume we already know the function as a complex function

Comment: $p(z)=w$ is a polynomial equation of degree $\ge1$ for every complex $w$, so it must have a solution.

Comment: Yes but the question is how can you take a function like that and show it is surjective without being told it is induced by a polynomial.

Comment: Take the map $(u,v)$, check CRE, form $f=u+iv$ and apply conditions from MO to $f$. Polynomials are always surjective once they are holomorphic since any non-constant $e^{h(z)}+c$ has at least exponential growth.

Comment: hmm, but isn't there still a problem because the conditions in MO ask you to know the coefficientens in the expression $f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_iz^i$ . Or how would we bound these?

Comment: Oh I think you mean just using the expression $e^{h(z)} + c$?

Comment: Sounds good, but how does one prove the expression $e^{h(z)} + c$ has exponential growth? I'm very rusty when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: [Entire function bounded by a polynomial is a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/143468/152568). If $h(z)$ is non-constant it must grow at least linearly.

Comment: thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I think I know exactly what you're looking for! Here's a theorem (source - example problem 4.2 in Fulton's Introduction to Algebraic Topology)

**Claim:** Let $g: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function such that for some integer $n \geq 1,$ $\frac{g(z)}{z^n}$ approaches a non-zero constant $a$ as $|z| \to \infty.$ Then $g$ is surjective.

Clearly polynomials fulfill this, and in some sense I believe this has what you want of "not knowing it's a polynomial".

**Proof of claim:** Assume there is $x \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}: g(z) \neq x.$ We apply the [Dog-on-a-Leash theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) (see Fulton for the exact details), and we try and compare $g$ and $az^n.$ WLOG $x = 0$ and $a > 0,$ and we picking an $\epsilon$ with $0<\epsilon<a$ we get that for large enough $r,$ the function $g$ restricted to the circle with radius $r$ centered at $0$ fulfills
$$|g(z)-az^n| < \epsilon |z|^n < a|z|^n = |a|z|^n-0|,$$
i.e. the distance of $g$ and $az^n$ is smaller than the distance of $az^n$ and $0.$ This proves that both must have the same winding number around 0. But $az^n$ has winding number $n,$ and $g,$ as a continuous function extendable to the entire disk of radius $r,$ must have winding number 0, a contradiction as $n \geq 1.$

Comment: Thank you very much +1. Although what I was looking for was a theorem that didn't "know" that the function comes from a complex function (in other words it is just presented as a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$, and we are able to use some more relaxed condition to verify it is surjective).