# Additional question on Entire function bounded by a polynomial is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I was reading this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143468/entire-function-bounded-by-a-polynomial-is-a-polynomial). Here we are only considering $\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$ to be bounded for large $|z|$, i.e, $\exists R>0 $ such that  $\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$ is bounded for $|z|\geq R$.
I was able to understand how we solved this question but I have an additional question.

> What will happen if $\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$ is bounded on whole of
> $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then $f(z)=kz^n$ for some constant $k$. That's because $0$ is a removable singularity of $\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$ and therefore, near $0$, $\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$ can be written as $a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots$. But then, by Liouville's theorem, $a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots=k$, for some constant $k$, and therefore $f(z)=kz^n$.