# Entire function bounded by a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f(z) $ be an entire function such that for some constant $\alpha$, $|f(z)| \leqslant \alpha |z|^3  $ for all $|z| \geqslant 1$
and $f(z)=f(iz)$ for all $z$.

then comment about existence of such function. 
**My work** $f$ will be polynomial of degree at most $3$
so $f(z) = a + bz + cz^2 + dz^3 \tag{1}$

$f(iz) = a + b(iz) + c(iz)^2 + d(iz)^3$ 
$f(z) = a +ibz - cz^2 -idz^3 \tag{2}$
comparing equation $1$ and $2$ we get $b=c=d=0$ 
hence $f(z)$ is constant polynomial.

Is this correct?

Comment: $\alpha$ does not appear in the condition.

Comment: @Gary yes it was mistake on my part, i forgot to add it. i have corrected it.

Comment: Perhaps you should justify your claim that $f$ will be a polynomial of degree at most $3$.

Comment: @Gary That has appeared too many times on MSE, so I think OP need not spell it out. Here is one instance: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143468/entire-function-bounded-by-a-polynomial-is-a-polynomial?rq=1

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I know why this is true, but perhaps this is a homework problem and the OP is required to post full solution.