Growth rate of entire function only integer values?
I'm currently preparing for an exam in complex analysis and vaguely remember our lecturer telling us that an entire function can only grow at the same rate as a monomial, i.e. there is no entire function satisfying:
$$ |z|^{1.1} < |f(z)| < |z|^{1.9} $$
In fact an old exam question asks wether a holomorphic function f on the domain |z|>1 can exist, satisfying the above inequality everywhere.
I tried using series expansion und triangle inequalities and Cauchy's integral formula, but can't quite prove this. Any help?
Edit: I restated the Problem because of my original poor choice of words.

Entire functions are by definition defined and  holomorphic in all of $\Bbb C$, so “an entire function f which exist on the domain $|z|>1$” makes no sense. – Do you mean a holomorphic function in the domain $|z| > 1$? Or do you mean an entire function which satisfies $|z|^{1.1} < |f(z)| < |z|^{1.9}$ for $|z| > 1$?

If the question is about an entire function then it is essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/143468/42969, where it is shown that $f$ must be a polynomial.

Consider the function
$$g : \mathbb{D} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{C}, \quad g(z) := f(\tfrac{1}{z}).$$
This function is holomorphic and satisfies
$$\lim\limits_{z \to 0} z^2g(z) = 0,$$
hence it has a pole of order at most one in $0$. On the other hand,
$$\lim\limits_{z \to 0} |zg(z)| = \infty,$$
so it also must have a pole of order at least two. Contradiction.
So essentially the growth rate is the order of the function at infinity. But the order of a holomorphic function is always an integer due to the Laurent expansion.

Thank you! This is quite elegant without the need of series expansion.
