# Entire function Problem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am new to complex analysis and I am facing difficulty in the following problem:

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function satisfying $|f(z)| \leq k|z|^2$ for some +ve constant k and all z. Show that $ f(z) = az^2$ for some constant a.

Which concepts will be used here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that if $|f(z)| \leq M |z|^n$ then $f$ is a polynomial max degree n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86772/show-that-if-fz-leq-m-zn-then-f-is-a-polynomial-max-degree-n)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entire function bounded by a polynomial is a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143468/entire-function-bounded-by-a-polynomial-is-a-polynomial)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an application of Liouville's theorem.

$|f(z)|\leq|(\sqrt{k}z)^2|\implies|\frac{f(z)}{(\sqrt{k}z)^2}|\leq1$ Notice that $f(z)$ and $(\sqrt{k}z)^2$ are both entire functions thus $\frac{f(z)}{(\sqrt{k}z)^2}$ is entire and it's also bounded therefore it's constant and the result follows.

Comment: To the answer above, observe that the obtained function is not necessarily entire. However, it can be extended to an entire function, for it is bounded in some neighbourhood of 0, which is its only singularity point. Liouville's theorem provides a constant that works for the new function, and so for the old one, as well.