# Entire function such that $\lim_{ z \to \infty} \frac{f(z)}{z^N} = 0$ then $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $N$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I am tried to prove this:

> Let a entire function $f$ such that $\lim_{ z \to \infty} \frac{f(z)}{z^N} = 0. $ Show that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $N$.

I find this results

> [Entire function bounded by a polynomial is a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143468/entire-function-bounded-by-a-polynomial-is-a-polynomial)

So, I start my proof asuming that if $f$ is entire, it is equal to a power series centered at 0 with radius of convergence $\infty$, and its Taylor series is

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(N)}(0)}{N!}z^N$$

and I have the [Cauchy formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) says:

$$\frac{f^{n}(z_0)}{n!} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-z_0|=r} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz$$

so if I consider $z_0 = 0$ and $$\frac{f^{n}(z_0)}{n!} {2\pi i} = \int_{|z|=r} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$

I tried to following the results of that, but I don't shure if I am in right way.

Can you help me to do it, please?

Comment: For $n>N$, prove that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$.

Comment: Hint: show that $f^{(n)}(z)$ is a bounded entire function. Conclude using Liouville's.

Comment: There exists $R$ such that $|f(z)| <|z|^{N}$ for $|z| \geq R$.  So $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $N$ (by the result you have quoted).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that if $|f(z)| \leq M |z|^n$ then $f$ is a polynomial max degree n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86772/show-that-if-fz-leq-m-zn-then-f-is-a-polynomial-max-degree-n)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entire function bounded by a polynomial is a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143468/entire-function-bounded-by-a-polynomial-is-a-polynomial)

Answer (score 2):

Hint following your idea: write $f^{(n)}(0)$ as line integral
$$
f^{(n)}(0) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\,dz
$$
and apply the bound:
$$\left|\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\,dz\right|\le \left(\sup_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)}{z^N}\right)\frac1{r^{n+1-N}} \,2\pi r= \cdots$$
What happens when $n$ is large (*how* large?) enough?

Comment: The integral is equals to 0 and $f^{(n)}(0) = 0 $ but why I say that $f$ is a polynomial of grande at most N? It's because in the $n-th $ derivative is 0 and that's the limit? and where I use the hipotesis of my $lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{f(z)}{z^N} = 0$

Comment: @Ops, the integral is $= 0$ for $n$ *large enough*. What is a Taylor series with coefficients $= 0$ for $n$ *large enough*?