# Characterize the set of functions $g:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}$ with the given property

Tags: complex-analysis

> Characterize the set of holomorphic functions $g:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}$ that are bounded away from zero with $|g(z)|>|z|^{-7/3}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$

I understand that from the inequality, it has a pole at $0$.

But other than that I really don't see a method to obtain the mentioned characterization.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Doesn't the inequality on the module of the function implies that it cannot be bounded?

Comment: I'm sorry. It was my mistake. I edited the question

Comment: You presumably mean holomorphic.

Comment: Yes. Thanks I edited

Comment: $\frac{1}{z}$ does not work for all $|z|<1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$. Then consider functions $h=f \circ g$. Then $|h(z)|<|z|^{\frac{7}{3}}$ Then, $h(z)$ is similar to a quadratic polynomial. This in turn characterises $g(z)$.

Comment: Thank you but why did you say that $h$ is similar to a quadratic polynomial?

Comment: @gune : Because it has a removable singularity at $z=0$ and must thus be an entire function. Now entire functions with such bounds are actually polynomials of the same or less degree,...

Comment: Oh I see. Removable singularity is there because $h$ is bounded. Right? 
And the polynomial property follows from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86772/show-that-if-fz-leq-m-zn-then-f-is-a-polynomial-max-degree-n 

Am I correct

Comment: As I mentioned, $\frac{1}{z}$ does not work as working for all $z$ without a constant to balance it out like in that link is very strict.

Comment: Thank you I edited the question

Comment: And I need a small clarification.  
So according to the obtained condition, $g(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$ should work. Isn't it? (Reciprocal of a quadratic function)  
But wouldn't that also have the same problem of satisfying the given inequality for $z$ close to $0$

Comment: Indeed. I believe the set of such functions is empty. I should have clarified that my answer was only a hint. You just need show no quadratic will work.

Comment: Than you very much!